# How to access Ambient Light Sensor in Chrome Web browser?

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, cross-browser, sensors

I am working on a Light Meter browser-based app. I want to measure the Ambient light in Lumens and display the same on the browser. I found there is a Google Sensors for Web API however, its not supported anymore? Can someone explain how to Access the Ambient Light sensor using a browser?
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/sensors-for-the-web
This flag in chrome enables the same. chrome://flags/#enable-generic-sensor-extra-classes However, this requires a Browser re-launch. Any method that I can get a user to enable this without browser re-launch?